# Is there any way to Monitor windows application in zabbix?

Tags: networking, remote-access, zabbix

I am trying to monitor an app that is installed in windows OS.I have already configured zabbix agent to monitor the windows device. Now,i want zabbix to gather data only from one specific app running.

What i want to monitor is app status, and also to make sure if the app has made request to specific website in last few minutes.

Comment: you could use proc.num[] or service.info[] see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys